# Why do I get the same vertices coordinates after obj collidess although setting frame_set()?

Tags: python, animation, physics, collision, timeline

I bake a physics simulation in a scene in which a couple of mesh objects are present. I want to obtain the vertices coordinates of one of the meshes in the scene from frame `10` up until the end of the simulation. However, after baking the physics, although I change the frame number, I still get the same vertices/location of that mesh (which moves and collides with other meshes in the scene) for each frame. I may note that the objects start colliding from frame `5` onwards. I wonder what am I doing wrong that I cannot get the right vertices coordinates/location of that mesh?

Here's the code snippet that is supposed to do change the frame number and get the location of the mesh:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for frameNo in range(10, 20):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frameNo)
    obj = bpy.data.objects["collidingObj"]
    print (obj.matrix_world.translation)
```

Which prints the following:

```
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3818)>
```

Also, using the code snippet below:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for frameNo in range(10, 20):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frameNo)
    obj = bpy.data.objects["collidingObj"]
    mat = obj.matrix_local
    coords = [mat * vert.co for vert in obj.data.vertices]
    xs = np.asarray([co.x for co in coords])
    ys = np.asarray([co.y for co in coords])
    zs = np.asarray([co.z for co in coords])
    print (xs.sum(), ys.sum(), zs.sum())
```

Results in:

```
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
-7.30156898499e-07 -1.34110450745e-06 112.716293335
```

Comment: Using an object with two keyframes, a rigid body simulation and a baked simulation, I get varying numbers in each situation. Are you sure the object you are using is one that moves within the frame range?

Comment: @sambler I'm not using two keyframes. Maybe that's why ... . Yes I'm sure the object is moving and collides with others within the frame range. The object actually starts moving from frame number 1 but the collision takes place around frame 5-8 always.

Comment: @sambler I just realized that when I save the mesh as .obj file the vertices and location changes. Does that give you a clue of what might be the problem? Do you think it's still related to the keyframes you mentioned earlier?

Comment: If it collides at frame 5 is it still moving at 10 when you start getting the coordinates or has it hit and stopped?

Comment: @sambler They continue colliding and moving up until frame 60 or son